# AngularJS: Why does $http not actually make a http request until you leave the current digest?

Tags: angularjs

The AngularJS documentation for $http at http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http states "The $http service will not actually send the request until the next $digest() is executed.".

I was just wondering why it does not just make the HTTP request immediately?  It seems like an unnecessary requirement, I wonder what I am missing.

UPDATE:  Its been suggested that this is necessary because the completion handlers will need to update the digest.  However, those completion events will need to make their own $apply/$digest call later either way.

Comment: Maybe you find this blog post interesting: http://www.benlesh.com/2013/08/angularjs-watch-digest-and-apply-oh-my.html
It answers your question I guess.

Comment: it is true when you call http outside of angular context but i think not in normal cases

Comment: Ajay is right.  The line you mention is in the section titled "Calling $http from outside AngularJS".  I don't know of anything in angular that happens outside of an angular `digest` cycle.  If you made the request inside of a `digest`, it would happen 'immediately'.

Comment: But why have the special behavior?  Why not just make an HTTP request in any case?

Comment: I think this is to make sure that the request is made with the correct data rather than the one you 'think' is the correct one.

Comment: Sorry Neikos I don't follow.

Comment: As I see this behavior changed from version 1.2.0, and http call actually would be triggered even when it called outside from $digest
Commit: https://github.com/cburgdorf/angular.js/commit/561186a075a1c5125959285e8c638a2e1c46364b
Discussion:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5206

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually because $http is promise based. Full explanation here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2794#issuecomment-18807158