# AngularJS $resource returns slow

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-resource

I have a really simple resource calling CakePHP. When I run the request using Advanced Rest Client it returns in ~100ms. In angular it takes 2-4 seconds. Below is the code I'm running to "prove" that resource is the bottleneck.

Resource:

```
var resource = $resource('/index.php/props/:op/:id.json', {}, {
    getPropertyListByCategory: { method:'GET', params:{ op:'getPropertyListByCategory', category:'@category' } },
    setPropertyListByCategory: { method:'POST', params:{ op:'setPropertyListByCategory' } }
});
```

Method:

```
function getPropertyListByCategory(params) {
    var x1 = Date.now();
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    resource.getPropertyListByCategory(params, function(resp) {
        var x2 = Date.now();
        console.log(x2-x1);
        deferred.resolve(resp.data);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

You can see I timestamp right before the resource call, then compare it to the resolve. Again when I run this request directly against Cake it returns super fast. Cake is not the problem.

Any ideas how I can speed this up a little bit?

Comment: what is the `resource` object you are calling the function `getPropertyListByCategory` on? Is it an Angular Service/Factory ?

Comment: Gah sorry. Editing the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### $resource is not slow

I wanted to put it inside a comment but it is too long to fit, so..

It might be tempting to think that **$resource** is the bottleneck here, but I suggest it's because you don't fully understand how asynchronous code works and more than that how angular works.

Your **"benchmark"** is not valid, it assumes the callback is invoked immediately, and no other code runs in between.

See this question: [AngularJS: Why does $http not actually make a http request until you leave the current digest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20605291/angularjs-why-does-http-not-actually-make-a-http-request-until-you-leave-the-c)

**$resource** uses **$http** which will not actually send the request until the next $digest() is executed.

Lots of things can make a $digest slow, you should check other parts of your application for it.

You may also create an angular test application with only $resource and see if it is still slow.

If you think about it , when was the last time you heard about an **angular.js** performance issue which do not involve $digest ?!

Again, What could be slow with $resource?! it's just a simple service.

---

```
function getPropertyListByCategory(params) {
    var x1 = Date.now();
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    // the request is queued and will run after a $digest!!
    resource.getPropertyListByCategory(params, function(resp) {

        var x2 = Date.now();
        deferred.resolve(resp.data);
    });

    // x3 is assigned before x2 ..

    var x3 = Date.now();

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: `ngRepeat` probably creating too much data bindings, 95% of cases.